# Reusing the same Thread

Tags: android

I have an `onClick()` method with a `Thread` inside that. The simplified structure is the following.

```
imageA = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageA);
imageA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {myThread.start();}
});

Thread myThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some stuff here
    }
};
```

Clicking a second time, I get the following error:

```
Thread already started
```

I have read in some forums that it is not a good idea to start a `Thread` more than once and that it is not enough to use:

```
if (!myThread.isAlive()){myThread.start();}
```

The suggested option is to create a new `Thread`. The problem is that reusing the same `Thread` is more comfortable for me. So questions are:

1. Is it true that I should avoid reusing the same `Thread`?
2. If yes, what is the best practice to rewrite that code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't start thread twice. Just look [at documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

2. You option is to use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) if you want to reuse threads. But it also depends on your specific case - what you want to do in your click handler. You also may look at AsyncTasks and Loaders.

Answer (score 1):

Thread instances can not use Twice.

If you want to reuse the same `Thread` for a series of tasks you should use `Looper` in a `Thread`.

```
 class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

Another Straight forward  alternative is use `HandlerThread`

```
class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {

    Handler handler;

    public MyHandlerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        handler = new Handler(getLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // process incoming messages here
                // this will run in non-ui/background thread
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then you can give task by passing messages

```
    //Create and send a new  message to looper
    fun sendMessage(messageToSend: String?) {
        //Create and post a new message to handler
        if (messageToSend != null && handler != null) {
            val encodeMessage = encodeMessage(messageToSend)
            handler!!.sendMessage(encodeMessage)
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Looper is not prepared or message is Null")
            sendResultToUI("Looper is not prepared or message is Null")
        }
    }

    private fun encodeMessage(messageToSend: String): Message {
        val message = Message()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_KEY, messageToSend)
        message.data = bundle
        return message
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking start method on an object of Thread ore than once will cause Exception. In case you need to reuse the thread then once its operation is done, you need to make it wait on an lock. When you need to reuse it then you need to notify it to wake. This is possible with help of an object, lets call it lock, upon whose once the task is done you need to invoke lock.wait() inside the synchronized block (synchronized on lock). When you need it again you simply can invoke lock.notify() agin in synchronized block (synchronized on lock).

You can avoid above complexcity by using Threadpool provided by Java concurrent package. Threadpool is a pool of thread objects. It handles the complexities of assigning the task to the free (or new, as per the chosed threadpool) thread and returning the object to pool of free thread objects once it executes the assigned work. When new task comes pool assigns the task to one of the free thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse threads use an ExecutorService with a thread pool of size 1 or how many threads you want to have and the executor will reuse them.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        executor.execute(() -> {

        });
```